# How to send low-level command (non-APDU) to a smartcard on Windows 10 (mobile)?

Tags: windows, nfc, win-universal-app, smartcard, apdu

I am writing code based on the [NFC Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Nfc) Microsoft provides.
Everything in [Windows.Devices.SmartCards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.aspx) is about APDU commands. For example, the TransmitAsync method is described as:

> Asynchronously transmits the supplied application protocol data unit (APDU) command and returns the response.

However, since this is a method with an argument of a byte array, I thought I was able to get rid of APDU by using this method. I inserted some code in the file CardReader.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task HandleCard(SmartCard card){
    ......
    // Handle MIFARE Standard/Classic
    LogMessage("MIFARE Standard/Classic card detected");
    var mfStdAccess = new MifareStandard.AccessHandler(connection);
    var uid = await mfStdAccess.GetUidAsync();
    LogMessage("UID:  " + BitConverter.ToString(uid));

    // My code
    LogMessage("==============");
    await SendBytes(connection, new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0, 0, 0 }); //APDU Test
    await SendBytes(connection, new byte[] { 0x50, 0x00 }); // Halt card
    await SendBytes(connection, new byte[] { 0x52 }); //Wake card
    return;
    ......
}
private async Task<byte[]> SendBytes(SmartCardConnection connection, byte[] RawData)
{
    LogMessage("> " + BitConverter.ToString(RawData).Replace("-", " ").ToUpper());
    byte[] res = (await connection.TransmitAsync(RawData.AsBuffer())).ToArray();
    LogMessage("< " + BitConverter.ToString(res).Replace("-", " ").ToUpper());
    return res;
}
```

I run the app on my phone to send commands to a Mifare Classic 1K card. However, what I get is:

```
> FF CA 00 00 00
< 02 27 9F 8F 90 00
> 50 00
< 63 00
> 52
< 63 00
```

Obviously the APDU one works. I have no idea what 63 00 is but I guess it is a SW response in an APUD command?
I saw on a forum that you are able to do that on an Android phone using NfcAdapter. What is wrong with my code? Or is it even possible to send low-level command (to get rid of APDU) on Windows 10 Mobile?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, how you arrived at the assumption, that "halt card" and "wake card" are understood by a primitive MIfare token. The commands are intended for a processor card, to signal, that the processor may switch to clock stop mode or return from it to reduce its power comsumption. Mifare cards have no processor, but hard-wired logic. I'm also also uncertain, what you hope to gain by getting rid of APDU structure except leaving a well-established path behind you.

Comment: Maybe I used a inappropriate example. There is a three-steps authentication between the reader and the card. I want to know more about it with low-level commands (without a proxmark). After anti-collision and card selection, if the reader sends 60 30 76 4a (block 30 auth.), the Mifare card is gonna respond with a 4-byte challenge. However, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send PCSC commands as anwsered by Maarten. There is a library written on c# that encapsulates low-level Mirafe commands to PCSC APDUs.

Check on [onovotny's repository](https://github.com/onovotny/MiFare)

Answer (score 0):

PCSC has commands specific to storage cards. This way you can get support for Mifare. You'd have to have support for Mifare cards from the reader manufacturer of course, but Mifare is still quite popular.

Native Mifare commands are however not supported. You need to convert those to the PCSC commands in the [2.01 specification](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/files/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf), section 3.2.2.1.

So you don't need to get rid of the native commands. Just send the storage card specific APDU's to the reader and the reader will send the native commands to the card.